# Array elements loaded with arrayWithContentsOfFile are null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I am currently working on a project in Objective-C in Xcode 5.
I have a file `Data.plist`, an array of `NSDictionaries`, which is in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">    

<array>       

<dict>
    <key>
        Name
    </key>
    <string>
        Robert Aderholt
    </string>
    <key>
        Party
    </key>
    <string>
        Republican
    </string>
</dict>
........
</array> 
</plist>
```

I am loading into a an array in with the following line:

```
 NSArray *arrayOfCongressMen =[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Data" ofType: @"plist"]];
```

I can successfully use `NSLog` in the following ways:

```
NSLog(@"Full array: %@",arrayOfCongressMen); //print successfully

NSLog(@"First dictionary of array: %@", arrayOfCongressMen[0]); //prints successfully
```

And finally:

```
NSLog(@"Object for key Name in the first dictionary of the array: %@", [arrayOfCongressMen[0] objectForKey:@"Name"]);
```

This last `NSLog` prints out `(null)` to the console.

Please help!

EDIT: SOLVED

The formatting of my `plist` file created line breaks and spacing, so my dictionary keys contained "\n"s and "    "s.

I fixed it by Ctrl-F and Replacing all spaces with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you should always do with debugging, break it down. After calling arrayWithContentsOfFile, do you get back an array?

If you fetch the first object from the array, what is it?

```
id firstObject = arrayOfCongressMen[0];

NSLog(@"first object class = %@", [firstObject class]);
```

Comment: Yep, I do get back the full array (of dictionaries)

The first object is a dictionary, which I can get properly

However, for some reason, I can't get any objects from the dictionary

Comment: Crap, nevermind. Thanks for your help! I went back to debug it like you said and it turns out that my `plist` file contained line breaks and spaces which causes the keys to mess up

Comment: When things don't work like you expect, go back and check your assumptions. Often it's something that is working differently than you think it is, so the results don't expect. The debugger is a great tool for figuring out what's **ACTUALLY** happening.